# Select the specific row from the DB having the date of tomorrow and day after tomorrow date from the present date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Considering the present date in my system as `2013-08-18 14:00:00.000`.I have to access the row from the database which has the date tomorrow and day after tomorrow of the present date i.e `2013-08-19 00:00:00.000` and `2013-08-20 00:00:00.000`
  For present instance I have tried with these lines of query.But its not working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [patientid], 
                apttime 
FROM   [patient_appointment_detail] 
WHERE  ( apttime > Getdate() + 1 ) 
        OR ( [apttime] > Getdate() + 2 )
```

This is my database elements

```
     PatientID               AppTime
AT0820130007        2013-08-19 14:00:00.000                         
AT0820130031        2013-08-22 17:00:00.000
```

Any help are apprieciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
...
WHERE
   cast(AptTime as date) 
   BETWEEN dateadd(day, 1, cast(getdate() as date)) 
       AND dateadd(day, 2, cast(getdate() as date))
```

Casting to data type `Date` removes the time portion.

(But be aware that might not use an appropriate index)

Comment: I think the first argument should be 1 NOT -1 and the second should be 2 NOT 1